# Eclipse上のSpringMVCのclasspathについて

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

お世話になっております。

現在Eclipse4.6上でSpringMMVCのWebアプリケーションを開発し,
プロパティファイルを指定したいためにservlet-context.xmlファイ上でaplication.propatiysビーンを指定したのですが、この際のclasspathの指定方法がよくわかりません。

フォルダー構造がどうも違っており、mainから直接resourceフォルダとはなっておりません。
この場合のclasspathが指定するトップレベルディレクトリはどこになるのでしょうか？
ご存じの方がいらっしゃればご教授いただければ幸いです。
`<beans:value>classpath:application.properties</beans:value>`

Answer (score 0):

お騒がせしました。
classpassを指定した場合、WEB-INF配下にあるclassesというフォルダを差していました。
ありがとうございました